# Send POST request via URL

Tags: http, parsing, html-parsing, http-post

There is an asp page on which i enter my Rollno and press submit, next page shows my result. Below is the source of form of the page.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Result.asp">

   <input name="Rollno" type="text" id="RollNo" size="15" maxlength="15">

   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value=" Search " onClick="return num();">

</form>
```

There is no way to see the  result for all students therefore i want to loop through all roll numbers to see my position. But i am unable to do it by writing search.asp?Rollno=123456

How to send the request via url so that i can loop through all numbers?

Comment: Need the whole picture here. How does your `search.asp` relate to `Result.asp`? Does the code snippet you provided reside in `Result.asp` or `Search.asp`? What does the `num()` function do? And why "There is no way to see the result for all students"?

Comment: Sorry for that, search.asp is the page where i write roll no, and Result.asp is the page where number is displayed. Only the person who knows his/her roll no can find his result. There is no option to see the score of others. Fortunately roll numbers are incremental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An HTTP POST request cannot be sent by using just an URL. (Except for the special case that there are no form fields and that the server doesn't care about the `Content-type` header.)

You should use an external program like `wget` or `curl`, which both can send either GET or POST requests.

Comment: And where is the POST request sent to? A URL, perhaps? And where's the correlation between `Content-Type` and an HTTP request method?

Comment: I want to make a simple application which will loop through the results, is it possible to do that with c# + curl or wget?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though I don't know how easy it will be. But when you are using C# in the first place, you should definitely have a look if the C# API provides a way to open an HTTP connection and maybe parse HTML. Using an external program usually involves more work.

Comment: Yes, c# does provide facility to send http request and also to parse html there is a library.